# Best way to create an angular 4 library

Tags: angular, npm

what's the best way to create an angular library ? 
I'd like to create some libraries to be added in my angular projects, providing common-case services, like a RestService to perform rest calls, AuthService for authentication, and some components too, (e.g ). The library should be distribute as an npm package.

Should I create the library "by hand", handling module loader/bundler, testing framework, typings etc, or I can go straight with angular/cli as explained [here](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/angular/) ?

Any comments?

Thanks

Comment: reading this: https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: [Alex Mercer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10904369) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66781925) saying "You can refer this article : [https://kazinizamul.medium.com/create-npm-package-library-from-scratch-in-angular-c78bbc585a23](https://kazinizamul.medium.com/create-npm-package-library-from-scratch-in-angular-c78bbc585a23). Explained elaborately."

Answer (score 2):

We have had good luck leveraging a starter project such as https://github.com/thakurinbox/angular-library-starter

All the boilerplate stuff is taken care of by the starter, and you simply add your code.  (Admittedly that particular starter does not have Karma configuration for unit testing, but that was fairly trivial to add).

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial tool by [David Herges](https://github.com/dherges) named
[ng-packagr](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr).

- first install this package:  npm install ng-packagr
- After installing add a file named ng-package.json to the root of your project.
  and edit it as bellow:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
    }
  }
}
```

- add this line of code to your packag.json file "scripts" property:

"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"

- add this public_api.ts file to the route of your project and export 
  the module in this file for example:

```js
export * from './src/app/modules/sample.module';
```

- When your module is ready just run this command: npm run packagr

a dist folder would be generated in your project.

- change directory into dist folder.
- npm login to enter your npmjs account
- npm publish to publish the version of the module which is 
  mentioned in your package.json

> Notice to export all needed components and services in your module.